# how run a unity project in flutter

Tags: android, flutter, unity-game-engine

I try to add my simple unity project to flutter but after build-in console I got an Error:

```
Lost connection to the device.
```

top of consol in vsCode I get these Error with red colour:

```py
Note: C:\Fproject\unity_flutter\android\UnityExport\src\main\java\com\unity3d\player\UnityPlayerActivity.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Note: C:\src\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\flutter_unity_widget-0.1.6+8\android\src\main\java\com\rexraphael\flutterunitywidget\FlutterUnityViewFactory.java uses unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
```

what should I do?? please help

Thanks a lot.

Comment: You are getting `Lost connection to deivce`. Can you do `flutter doctor -v` and show me the result here?

Comment: @Alok these are the Result: I send them 
Separately

Comment: PS C:\Fproject\unity_flutter> flutter doctor -v
[√] Flutter (Channel stable, v1.17.5, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.18362.836], locale en-US)
    • Flutter version 1.17.5 at C:\src\flutter
    • Framework revision 8af6b2f038 (5 weeks ago), 2020-06-30 12:53:55 -0700
    • Engine revision ee76268252
    • Dart version 2.8.4

Comment: [√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 29.0.3)
    • Android SDK at C:\Users\patris10\AppData\Local\Android\sdk
    • Platform android-29, build-tools 29.0.3
    • Java binary at: C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio1\jre\bin\java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_212-release-1586-b04)
    • All Android licenses accepted.

Comment: [√] Android Studio (version 3.6)
    • Android Studio at C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio1
    • Flutter plugin version 48.0.1
    • Dart plugin version 192.8052
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_212-release-1586-b04)

Comment: [√] VS Code (version 1.47.3)
    • VS Code at C:\Users\patris10\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code
    • Flutter extension version 3.13.1

[√] Connected device (1 available)
    • Android SDK built for x86 64 • emulator-5554 • android-x64 • Android 10 (API 29) (emulator)

• No issues found!

Comment: Hmm... Okay, as far the as the result is concerned. It looks fine. Behnam **could you run the project on your real android device please**? The command is `flutter run` only, make sure your real device has **Debug option enabled**

Comment: @Alok  thanks so much for your help                                                                 
   when I build it in real device it run sucsessfuly..                                                               so what is the problem with android emulator my friend?? and I cant build apk too..when I use flutter build apk

Comment: Added building data to my answer behnam

Comment: Hi @behnam,
Could you please show me how to add unity project to Flutter.
Many Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After the result you saw, I believe answering your question would help a lot of people who will just start off with this.

The solution is to **use your real device and run the project using `flutter run`**.

**Why success in real device and failure in emulator?**

> Many a times, an emulator doesn't supports some functionalities. The real device has a perfect engine to support all of them, hence you get the problem sorted.

**To Build apk**

> flutter build apk --release

Consider reading upon this documentation: [Build and release an Android app](https://flutter.dev/docs/deployment/android)